# Remove If block with FunctionDef keeping the untouched code as it is

Tags: python, tokenize, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to replace the if-else section with a function enclosing the same if-else. For ex:

Following is the code with if-else condition

```
x = 5 # comments to be retained

# above new line as well
if foo() == 'bar':
   y = 10
   print('foo is bar')
else:
   print('foo is not bar')
z =100
```

Now I want to change this

```
x = 5 # comments to be retained

# above new line as well
def if_encapsulated():
   if foo() == 'bar':
      y = 10
      print('foo is bar')
   else:
      print('foo is not bar')
if_encapsulated()
z = 100
```

I am using `ast` to parse the code and using `ast.NodeTransformer` to replace `if` using `ast.FunctionDef` but when I use `ast.unparse`/`astor.code_gen.to_source` it doesn't keep track of tabs, newline and remove comments. I want to replace `if` block and keeping the rest of the code as it is.

Here is the code for parsing and replacing if:

```
import ast
import astor
class IfReplacer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_If(self, if_node):
        function_node = ast.FunctionDef(name = "if_encapsulated", args=ast.arguments(posonlyargs=[], args=[], kwonlyargs=[], defaults=[]), body=[if_node], decorator_list=[], returns = None)
        return function_node

code = """

x = 5 # comments to be retained

# above new line as well
if foo() == 'bar':
   y = 10
   print('foo is bar')
else:
   print('foo is not bar')
z =100
"""
tree = ast.parse(code)
IfReplacer().visit(tree)
print(astor.code_gen.to_source(tree))
# ast.unparse(tree) doesn't work for FunctionDef as it raise error - no attribute called lineno
```

Outputs:

```
x = 5


def if_encapsulated():
    if foo() == 'bar':
        y = 10
        print('foo is bar')
    else:
        print('foo is not bar')


z = 100
```

I have tried using `asttokens` library which seems to resolve the such issue but when I use I faced another issue. And also explored `astor` again and faced some issues. Please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ast` module does not preserve comments and original formatting. Instead, you can use a library such as [`libcst`](https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST/) to generate an abstract syntax tree that does include comments, etc:

```
import libcst
import libcst._nodes as ln
def create_node(ast, **kwargs):
   return type(ast)(**{**{i:getattr(ast, i) for i in ast.__slots__}, **kwargs})

def make_updates(ast):
   if hasattr(ast, 'body'):
       body = []
       for i in ast.body:
          if isinstance(i, ln.statement.If) and i.orelse is not None:
             body.append(ln.statement.FunctionDef(
                 name = ln.expression.Name(value = 'if_encapsulated'),
                 params = ln.expression.Parameters(params = []),
                 body = ln.statement.IndentedBlock(body = [create_node(i, leading_lines = [])]),
                 leading_lines = i.leading_lines))
             body.append(ln.statement.SimpleStatementLine(body = [
                ln.statement.Expr(value = ln.expression.Call(
                   func = ln.expression.Name(value = 'if_encapsulated')))]))
          else:
             body.append(i)        
       return create_node(ast, body = body)
   return ast
```

```py
code = """
x = 5 # comments to be retained

# above new line as well
if foo() == 'bar':
   y = 10
   print('foo is bar')
else:
   print('foo is not bar')
z =100
"""

lib_ast = libcst.parse_module(code)
updated_ast = make_updates(lib_ast)
print(updated_ast.code)
```

Output:

```
x = 5 # comments to be retained

# above new line as well
def if_encapsulated():
   if foo() == 'bar':
      y = 10
      print('foo is bar')
   else:
      print('foo is not bar')
if_encapsulated()
z =100
```

Comment: Hi Ajax, Thanks for the answer, but wanted to know if you know anything about `asttokens`, and why it is not working. Otherwise, I have to move my code to `libcst` library. If possible can you also point out why I should use `libcst`.

Comment: And, how this function `create_node(ast, **kwargs)` is being used?

Comment: @Devavrata Unfortunately, `ast` does not preserve comments (and neither does `asttokens` in its own `ast` representation), so `libcst` is probably the next best option. `create_node` is creates a new `ast` node object, such as a function object for `if_encapsulated`.

Comment: Actually, I have started using `libcst` and this is the thing I was looking for the past week. It worked smoothly. Thank you

Comment: Instead of the custom `create_node()`, we can use the `node.with_changes(**changes)` method that comes with `libcst`.